# C++ memcpy to end of an array

Tags: c++, memcpy

I'm trying to translate C++ into C# and I'm trying to understand, conceptually what the following piece of code does:

```
memcpy( pQuotes + iStart, pCurQuotes + iSrc, iNumQuotes * sizeof( Quotation ) );
```

pQuotes is declared: **struct Quotation *pQuotes**.
**pCurQuotes** is a **CArray** of **struct Quoataion**, **iSrc** being it's first index. **iNumQuotes** is the number of elements in **pCurQuotes**.

What I would like to know is, if iStart is to pQuotes' last index, would the size of pQuotes be increased to accommodate the number of elements in pCurQuotes? In other words, is this function resizing the array then appending to it?

Thanks.

SethMo

Answer (score 2):

> If iStart is to pQuotes' last index, would the size of pQuotes be
>   increased to accommodate the number of elements in pCurQuotes? In
>   other words, is this function resizing the array then appending to it?

No.

This is a fundamental limitation of these low-level memory functions. It is your responsibility as the developer to ensure that all buffers are big enough so that you never read or write outside the buffer.

Conceptually, what happens here is that the program will just copy the raw bytes from the source buffer into the destination buffer. It does not perform any bounds- or type-checking. For your problem of converting this to C# the second point is of particular importance, as there are no type conversions invoked during the copying.

Answer (score 1):

> would the size of `pQuotes` be increased to accommodate the number of elements in `pCurQuotes`?

No. The caller is expected to make sure *before* making a call to `memcpy` that `pQuotes` points to a block of memory sufficient to accommodate `iStart+iNumQuotes` elements of size `sizeof(Quotation)`.

If you model this behavior with an array `Quotation[]` in C#, you need to extend the array to size at or above `iStart+iNumQuotes` elements.

If you are modeling it with `List<Quotation>`, you could call `Add(...)` in a loop, and let `List<T>` handle re-allocations for you.

Comment: Could I resize pQuotes array directly dynamically, then append to it without the memcpy?

Comment: @Sethmo011 Do you mean in C++? Yes, you could append to an array without `memcpy`. In fact, this would be a much more universal approach, because proper copy constructors would be used (`memcpy` would work only for objects with trivial copy constructors).

Comment: Thanks. Ideally, I want to do the operations in C#, however, as a last resort, I can just write a C++ dll and return the result to C#. That's the problem I've been having, appending to pQuotes. I thought memcpy in the original code was a neat way of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

**No, memcpy does not do any resizing**. pQuotes is merely a pointer to a space in memory, and the type of pointer determines its size for pointer arithmetic.

All that memcpy does is copy n bytes from a source to a destination. You need to apply some defensive programming techniques to ensure that you do not write beyond the size of your destination, because memcpy won't prevent it!

Comment: Would that cause an overflow?

Comment: Yep, you'll get a buffer overflow as memcpy will trample over some other data elsewhere. The worst thing is that you won't get any sort of error from it happening, and nothing untoward may actually happen for a very long time.